# mysql join extracted number

Tags: mysql, regex, join

I have a 'big' table like this

```
    id  user type comment
    6   1    A    id '3' - #8
    7   1    A    id '3' - #9
    8   3    B    
    9   3    B
```

I want to extract the numbers after the hash and join it with the id column to have the following (when the number between the single quotes is equal to the user)

```
    id1 id2  user  type
    6   8    3     B
    7   9    3     B
```

Comment: any common field? can you put the table structure?

Comment: id and user (int 11), type and comment (varchar 55)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A create a copy of your table, its name is bigtable and insert those values that you gave us:

```
mysql> create table bigtable (id int, user_id int, type varchar(10), comment varchar(30));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> insert into bigtable values (6,1, 'A', 'id 3 - #8'),(7,1,'A', 'id 3 - #9'),(8,3, 'B','' ),(9,3, 'B','');
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from bigtable;
+------+---------+------+-----------+
| id   | user_id | type | comment   |
+------+---------+------+-----------+
|    6 |       1 | A    | id 3 - #8 |
|    7 |       1 | A    | id 3 - #9 |
|    8 |       3 | B    |           |
|    9 |       3 | B    |           |
+------+---------+------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I did a self join and use the substrn_index function:

```
mysql> select b1.id,b2.id,b1.user_id,b1.type 
from bigtable as b1 join bigtable as b2 
on b1.id=SUBSTRING_INDEX(b2.COMMENT,'#',-1);
+------+------+---------+------+
| id   | id   | user_id | type |
+------+------+---------+------+
|    8 |    6 |       3 | B    |
|    9 |    7 |       3 | B    |
+------+------+---------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I hope this helped you